# Generation of ARIMA.sim

Tags: r, model, time-series

I have generated an ARIMA Model for data I have and need to simulate the model generated into the future by 10 years (approximately 3652 days as the data is daily). This was the best fit model for the data generated by auto.arima, my question is how to simulate it into the future?

```
mydata.arima505 <- arima(d.y, order=c(5,0,5))
```

Comment: In my opinion your question is not clear. What do you mean by This was the best fit model for the data generated by auto.arima"? Cannot find any fitted arima model in your question. In order to give a precice answer you should provide your full code and give the complete output of your estimation.

Comment: I have a time series of univariate data which I would like to use a ARIMA model on as it contains trend within the data, then use that ARIMA model to forecast the trends trajectory into the future.

Comment: What kind of trend do you expect? Arima cannot handle deterministic trends.

Answer (score 2):

The `forecast` package has the `simulate.Arima()` function which does what you want. But first, use the `Arima()` function rather than the `arima()` function to fit your model:

```
library(forecast)
mydata.arima505 <- arima(d.y, order=c(5,0,5))
future_y <- simulate(mydata.arima505, 100)
```

That will simulate 100 future observations conditional on the past observations using the fitted model.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is to simulate an specific arima process you can use the function `arima.sim()`. But I am not sure if that really is what you want. Usually you would use your model for predictions.

```
library(forecast)
# True Data Generating Process
y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.4, ma = 0.5, order =c(1,0,1)), n=100)

#Fit an Model arima model
fit <- auto.arima(y)

#Use the estimaes for a simulation 
arima.sim(list(ar = fit$coef["ar1"], ma = fit$coef["ma1"]), n = 50)

#Use the model to make predictions
prediced values <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 50)
```

Comment: How is the value for the ar (ar=0.3) component selected?

Comment: It is an arbitrary choise. But if you have estimated the coefficients you could plug simply in the estimate. But I am not sure if you really want to simulate a process. Are you sure you want that or do you actually want to predict?